# How can I fix this algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

I am trying to create a function in Python. This function should be able to create a list of whole numbers less than or equal to the number provided. I've created an empty list, a variable called `y` and a while loop. In this while loop, as long as `y <= x`, the results of the subsequent equations are appended to the empty list, and `y` increments by `1`. However, when I call this function, I get a list with only one element. How can I fix this?

```
def fff(x):
    numbers = []
    y = 2
    while(y <= x):
        x = x - (x - y)
        numbers.append(x)
        y += 1
    return numbers

>>> fff(10)
[2]
```

Comment: Why are you modifying `x`? Why aren't you appending `y`?

Comment: `fff=lambda x:  fff(x-1) + [x] if x > 1 else [1]` ... it will only work on numbers less than 1000 or so though ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley, what is this, Lisp?

Comment: lol naw i figured it was a fun way to answer given that this is obviously homework ... but it wasnt a real answer(eg sub-optimal and not very clear) so i put it as a comment

Answer (score 4):

That function already exists, more or less.

Python 2

```
def fff(x):
    return range(1,x+1)
```

Python 3

```
def fff(x):
    return list(range(1,x+1))
```

Comment: I mean I assume this is homework and so they can't use ``range``, but if it's not then totally.

Comment: @aruisdante, perhaps. If so, that should included in the OP. Otherwise, subsequent visitors will come here and starting writing their own `range`.

Comment: I added an answer as I think if the OP is indeed trying to replicate range with his code I think showing him is probably a good idea,

Comment: This isn't homework. I did realize my own mistake though, however, I didn't change it to the way you showed me.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this line `x = x - (x - y)` and think of your inputs, you will see the problem. if x initially equals 10,  then x - (x - y) equals 2, and y will equal 3, therefore breaking out of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to mimic the range function then this is how you would do it:

```
def fff(x):
    numbers = []
    y = 1
    while(y <= x):
        numbers.append(y)
        y += 1
    return numbers
```